# Not Able to Consume WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to consume the following WCF Service. 
http://staging.timatic.aero/timaticwebservices/timatic3services?WSDL

Here is my binding

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="timatic3servicesPort2" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://staging.timatic.aero:80/timaticwebservices/timatic3services"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="timatic3servicesPort2"
    contract="TimaticStag.timatic3servicesPort" name="timatic3servicesPort1" />
</client>
```

and Here is my code

```
TimaticStag.timatic3servicesPort timatic3serviceportStg = new TimaticStag.timatic3servicesPortClient();
TimaticStag.processLoginRequest longinRequestStg = new TimaticStag.processLoginRequest();
longinRequestStg.processLogin = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
timatic3serviceportStg.processLogin(longinRequestStg);
```

Whenever i am trying to call the processLogin(), I am getting exception

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/beta:processLoginResponse. The InnerException message was 'Element processLoginResponse from namespace http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/beta cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Is there anything i am doing wrong ?

Edit 1- Added Inner exception for more details.

```
Element processLoginResponse from namespace http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/beta cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML.
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the error?  It could be an error with the service or an error converting the response xml to an object.

Comment: The contract says that **processLogin** is an `object` type, are you sure that service expects a guid?

Comment: Its Getting quite messy here, When i tried it to consuming though the Java, ProcessLogin() has totally different set of parameters where as with .Net its has totally different set of parameters. Any Idea on it? For more info https://staging.timatic.aero/timaticwebservices/timatic3.WSDL, try it with java and .Net